# Xamarin.Forms line break text from WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

My ASP.NET WebAPI project is exposing a **speakers** endpoint:
There is a ton of text in the **AboutLong** property, that should be "broken" into several paragraphs.

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "FullName": "JohnDoe",
        "ImageUrl": "uriOfTheImage",
        "AboutShort": "CEO of AcmeCompany.",
        "AboutLong": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\nLorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.\nIt has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "ContactInfo": null
    },
```

========================================================================

I would like to show the AboutLong on my SpeakerDetailPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout Margin="16" Padding="0" Spacing="0">
        <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="32" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,16,0,0" />
        <Label Text="{Binding AboutShort}" FontSize="22" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,24" />
        <Label Text="{Binding AboutLong}" FontSize="16" />
```

========================================================================

When I put in the X.F line breaks manually, it works:

```
<Label Text="abcdefgh &#10; ijklmnop" />
```

However, if I just bind to the model (BindingContext is set to the model that was created from a deserialized json string), the emulator shows the text along with all the line break characters - \n

I've also tried to replace the \n with Xamarin.Forms line breaks - 

but then it shows the X.F line breaks as the text.

**How do we make API endpoints leave a clue for the client that there should be a line break in the text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this happened (Xamarin.Forms updated?), but suddently the '\n' works in the text how it's supposed to. It breaks lines.


I didn't change anything.
The API endpoint that I requested from the server is deserialized into an object. The object has an AboutLong property with value of a long string of text with '\n' characters.


The labels Text property is bound to the object's AboutLong property. This time Xamarin reads it correctly.


**I would be thankful if somebody would explain to me how this could have happened.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that those \n characters are handled as plain text so you won't get a line break. You should create a ValueConverter that takes the long string and replaces each newline character with `Environment.NewLine`, like this:

```
public class TextBrakeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string).Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:TextBrakeConverter x:Key="TextBrakeConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Label Text="{Binding LongText, Converter={StaticResource TextBrakeConverter}}" />
```